# Update from Select/find in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In mysql or other relational databases you can update from a select like

```
 update table1 set field1 = (select field1 from table1 where table1.id=2) where table1.id = 1;
```

Is there a way to do this in mongoDB?

Comment: `findAndModify` is probably what you want.

Comment: Am I correct that you want to perform an `update` operation based on a result of some `find` (select) operation?

Comment: tymeJV - Not sure that this can do what I want...
Leonid - Yes, but the update has to be overwriting a field of the found document with a field of a different one.

Comment: Never mind, I just ended up running a script, setting what I wanted to a javascript variable, and using the normal update/set to change the field I needed.